# How can I halt and start again without mesh moving while it is stopped?

Tags: animation

Can anyone tell me how I can move in a walking pose and then halt for some other gestures around the characters body and then take a few more steps afterwards without the mesh moving towards the location key frame for the next set of steps while it is supposed to be halted conducting other gestures?

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out. I just had to go and reset some of my previous location keys. That's all.